# QField buffer on select geometry point

Tags: buffer, select, qfield

[image]On my QGIS project i have a lots of points. I create a personal rule when I select a geometry (point), the selection create a view of a buffer area for a single point. I use this command on my symbology:

```
personal rule: is_selected ()
label -> geometry genereator -> buffer($geometry,250)
```

This comand working very well on QGIS but when I transfer the project on QField and I use the android app this didn't work anymore. I try a second way using the simple symbol 250 map units and personal rule always the comand is_selected(), this work on QGIS but not on QField. What can I do?

Comment: By personal rule do you mean rule base symbology ? if no where did you input this rule ? could you add screenshot of your setting ?

Comment: Hi @J.R yes is base symbology rule. I add a screenshot of my setting and what i expected how result on Qfield mobile app